# Class instead of getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) script and it gives me JavaScript code to add to my project. Something like:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementById('datepicker') });
```

Is there any way to use a class instead of `getElementByID`? For example:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field: $('.datepicker') });
```

Comment: `var picker = new Pikaday({ field: $('.datepicker').get(0) });` - looks like the plugin takes a DOM element - so use a DOM element.

Comment: You want the first datepicker? Or all of them in an array?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('datepicker')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are only using newer browsers you can use

```
document.querySelector('.datepicker')
```

This will give you the first element that matches the class. Here is the Caniuse link http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector

For older browsers you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('datepicker')[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the *first* element found by `getElementsByClassName()`:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({ field: document.getElementsByClassName('datepicker')[0] });
```

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list, but the constructor wants a single element.